# Styling a tooltip (popper.js / bootstrap v4 beta)

Tags: tooltip, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I've installed bootstrap v4 beta and with it the popper.js (tooltip.js) library. I'm trying to use it's tooltip function. So I managed to make it appear but I can't change it's appearance/style for the life of me. I've looked over their documentation several times but I can't figure it out. (I just hate a so called "documentation" that doesn't have examples). 
So here is my html:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Simple Task Management</span>
```

I activated it on data-toggle in js:

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

I noticed that when the tooltip appears a new div is created with the class "tooltip ..." so I thought I could target that class and style it in my scss, so:

```
.tooltip {
    background-color: #DB2828;
    color: $green;  
}
```

Not my intended styling options, just tested to see it work...well the result:
[image]

The same black background with my test background behind it...can someone help me figure this out? Many thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The structure of the tooltip is [described in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#options). To change the style you need to override `tooltip-inner` <strike>and `arrow`</strike>:

**Update for Bootstrap 4.0.0**

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/BeGG18qglJ/bootstrap-4-tooltip-style)

```
.tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #00cc00;
}
.tooltip.bs-tooltip-right .arrow:before {
    border-right-color: #00cc00 !important;
}
.tooltip.bs-tooltip-left .arrow:before {
    border-left-color: #00cc00 !important;
}
.tooltip.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow:before {
    border-bottom-color: #00cc00 !important;
}
.tooltip.bs-tooltip-top .arrow:before {
    border-top-color: #00cc00 !important;
}
```

(where `#00cc00` is the desired tooltip color)

Comment: Thank you, that worked, I was wondering if you could tell how you found out what to change. Where can you find this information?

Comment: I agree...I would have never known about the :before bits by looking at those docs.

Comment: p.s. I found that I needed to set arrow:before but NOT .arrow otherwise my arrow was stub-nosed...and p.p.s. for those using Angular-4, you'll have to put these css rules in global styles.css because the tooltip is created outside the component's DOM (assuming you are creating the tooltip in a "component").

Comment: @ZimSystem unfortunately this code to change the color doesn't work with bootstrap 4.0. The arrow gets all messed up and I can't understand why... https://www.codeply.com/go/IB7hqLqa2u. (and I've looked at the scss file - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_tooltip.scss)

Comment: It's explained in the last comment. remove `.arrow` from the custom CSS: https://www.codeply.com/go/2rMqYxkcIf

Comment: I needed `!important` in the first class element as well

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to do this instead for the bottom tooltip :

```
.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: $darkGrayClr;
}
.tooltip.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow:before {
  border-bottom-color: $darkGrayClr;
}
```